# RPAD Numeric values

Tags: sql, postgresql

This works fine in Oracle, but not Postgres. Does postgres allow for padding of numeric zeros?

```
RPAD(REPLACE(CAST(CEIL(MOD(columntimesec, 60)) / 100 AS VARCHAR(3)) , '.','0:'),4,0)
```

This works, but i'd like to pad with numeric values instead

```
RPAD(REPLACE(CAST(CEIL(MOD(columntimesec, 60)) / 100 AS VARCHAR(3)) , '.','0:'),4,'0')
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `columntimesec` is a "time of day" (i.e. between 00:00 and 23:59:59) then use `make_time` and format the output:

```
to_char(make_time(sec => columntimesec), 'hh24:mi')
```

If `columntimesec' is a duration, then convert it into an interval and format it using to_char:

```
to_char(make_interval(secs => columntimesec), 'hh24:mi')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to see the time in hh:mi:ss, then you can consider using

```
      LPAD(MOD(FLOOR(MOD(columntimesec,86400)/ 3600)::int,3600)::text,2,'0')||
':'|| LPAD(MOD(FLOOR(MOD(columntimesec,86400)/ 60)::int,60)::text,2,'0')||
':'|| LPAD(MOD(MOD(columntimesec,86400), 60)::text,2,'0') AS time
```

If the part containing `mi:ss` is enough for you then extract this part only :

```
      LPAD(MOD(FLOOR(MOD(columntimesec,86400)/ 60)::int,60)::text,2,'0')||
':'|| LPAD(MOD(MOD(columntimesec,86400), 60)::text,2,'0') AS time
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3b2fdad71b03201a9322d998a421d863)</kbd>